# How to retrieve tables from database tables based on 1s and 0s?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 2 tables at the moment: Artists and Genres.

Genres are connected to artists using artist_id. The phpmyadmin genres table is set up as follows:

[image]

1s indicates that the artist with id=3, has selected classical and rap using a checkbox.

I would like to efficiently display a card, which will display the artist genres in a list. For every 1 in the row where artist_id = $id , output all genres ( in our case, classical and rap).

I was thinking about creating a new object called artistgenre, and using `new artistgenre();` to create a new object and assign attributes. Maybe I don't even need to do that. Currently I have an object called artist, and I create `$artist = Artist::findbyid($sessionid);` and use `$artist->name; $artist->location;` to output data from the database.

Comment: the db-design is not efficient IMHO. The genre-table should (only) have `id, genre_name`. Then have another table that connects artists with genres n2n. (with `arist_id, genre_id`)

Comment: @Jeff I see what you mean, I list all genres in the genre_name, with each of them having a separate id. Then create another 3rd table called artistgenre with (id, artist_id, genre_id) and fetch the results where artist_id=$id. I don't understand how I'd retrieve such data, and what would happen if I had for explample another table like instruments? Is it possible to use 1 single table to list both the genres and instruments played by the artist?

Comment: @GRS Jeff's comment regarding design is correct. For Instruments, you would repeat the pattern, e.g. create a table called artist_instrument. To retrieve the related records, you will need to use SQL joins. It looks like you're using Eloquent so I would suggest you read the entire page here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @JoeNiland Thanks, I'm not using laravel, only basic php and mysql. I managed to get a list of genres played by the artist by using SELECT genre_id FROM artists JOIN artist_genres ON artists.id=artist_genres.artist_id   . Now this gives me a list of genre_ids, which I need to link to the genre table, and export via php in an array or something like that. Could you suggest me the correct way?

Comment: In other words I need to export genre_name where genre_id= list of id's from the previous SQL query

Answer (score 0):

I think this query is what you need:

```
SELECT g.id, g.name
FROM artists a 
  INNER JOIN artist_genres ag ON a.id = ag.artist_id
  INNER JOIN genres g ON ag.genre_id = g.id
```